# How do I get around HttpError 403 Insufficient Permission? (gmail API, Python)

Tags: python, gmail

I keep getting the following error when I execute my code:

> An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">

This is my code:

```
import httplib2
import os
from httplib2 import Http

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

#SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/'
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Quickstart'

def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatability with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print 'Storing credentials to ' + credential_path
    return credentials

def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64 encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}

testMessage = CreateMessage('ENTER SENDERS EMAIL ADDRESS', 'ENTER RECEIVERRS EMAIL ADDRESS', 'ENTER SUBJECT', 'ENTER EMAIL BODY')

def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print 'Message Id: %s' % message['id']
    return message
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error


testSend = SendMessage(service, 'me', testMessage)
```

I keep reading that I need to edit a credentials file, but I can't seem to find it. I have windows 7 installed. Does anyone know what I need to do in order to get past this error? I'm a totally new to this so please excuse me if I seem a bit new about this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Even though the accepted answer is 100% correct. I think it's worth pointing out that why that's the case.

When you authorize a gmail service client, you can specify several different scopes: All, compose, labels, etc...

These are all listed here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

The scope mentioned in the answer provides complete gmail access.

Comment: github link is broken... :(

Comment: yeah, github link is broken

Comment: I found the scopes available here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

Comment: fixed the link in the answer

Comment: NOTE: For the NEW scope to take effect, you might need to delete the file at "~/.credentials/gmail-python-quickstart-.json" (as noted here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python )

Comment: I had to delete the `token.pickle` file to be able to authorize the app again and make the changes in SCOPES have effect

Answer (score 16):

Solved it by changing the SCOPES line to:

```
SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'
```

Email sending works perfectly

Answer (score 11):

Gmail API has these scopes: 
[image: gmail api scopes]

For sending emails, **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send** is needed or full access https://mail.google.com/.

The scopes taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes#gmail_scopes).

Answer (score 9):

If you run the official "[gmail-python-quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample)" before, please delete the file "gmail-quickstart.json" in your system. Rerun your program again so that you can set the priviledge as you want.

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to the answers from:

1. ccy
2. apadana
3. ragnampiza

and as a furtherance of ccy's answer...

---

### Solution 1...

#### ... a hack fix

If you're using the original `gmail-python-quickstart` code, make sure to also update the following:

1. CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = `'/path/to/your/secret_client.json'`
2. Force `get_credentials()` to use the failed credentials logic path...

```
if True:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
```

to force `True` so that the logic operation will definitely work the `client.flow` operations:

```
if True:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
```

This is a hacky fix, but will get you up and going in short time.

#### The Problem...

- The problem with this approach is that it forces the `flow` code, which opens up the authentication window browser and requires that the end user accept the security protocol before sending the email.
- This obviously breaks the concept of automated email generation and sending.

---

### Solution 2...

#### ...a stable, more automated solution

I found that doing the following works:

1. Copy the downloaded the `secret-client-####.html.json` file to the directory defined in the first block of code from the `get_credentials()` method. Basically, copy it to your `user/.credentials` directory
2. Delete the current `gmail-python-quickstart.json`
3. Rename your downloaded file to `gmail-python-quickstart.json`

Run your code, and then it should work fine.

#### Benefits...

- The authentication page does not show up
- The email is sent automatically

Answer (score 2):

If you used google's official example, there should be a folder in `~/.credentials/` directory which is old, remove everything inside that directory and re-run your code. then you have to add new permissions and then everything is OK!

Comment: this worked for me..it is clearly mentioned in 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

Answer (score 0):

I had to do these steps:

- copy my credentials.json to another file
- delete credentials.json
- re paste to the new credentials.json
- rerun the app

to get it to work. Deleting token.json was not working for me.